# printf goes to new line where it shouldn't

Tags: c

when i launch this 2 lines of code

```
printf("|%-16s|%-16s|%-16d|\n","name","surname", 30);
printf("|%-16s|%-16s|%-16d|\n", database_publishers[pointer1].name, database_publishers[pointer1].client, database_publishers[pointer1].price);
```

it gives me output like this:

```
|name            |surname         |30              |
|name
           |surname
        |30              |
```

image:
[image]

variables in second printf call were got from user in other function, using fgets call like this

```
fgets(database_publishers[pointer].name, STRING_SIZE, stdin);
```

there are no any \n in this function and i have no idea why does it print every variable in new line. btw i work in visual studio, maybe it matters, idk, im just a rookie in programming

Comment: Please post your output as text and not as image so that the question will not break in the future and it is easier to read/copy. Can you check the length of the strings that you are printing?

Comment: `fgets()` also saves the **newline** character in the buffer, but we can only guess...

Comment: @mame98 ive added output as text. i just copied it from console, but im not sure if i ve done it right

Answer (score 1):

Text that is read using fgets does most-likely contains a newline at the end. You can test for this and remove it if required. Try to add the following piece of code before you try to print out the result:

```
size_t length = strlen(database_publishers[pointer].name);
if(database_publishers[pointer].name[length - 1] == '\n')
    database_publishers[pointer].name[length - 1] = '\0';
```

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443793/fgets-includes-the-newline-at-the-end), the above is basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443806/3700391) awnser.

Otherwise, if there is a newline character, your output will look like this:

```
|name            |surname         |30              |
|name<newline>
<remaining whitespace> | <...>
```

Comment: It looks like name and surename both contain newlines, which seems to be supported by the answer that the OP just posted (using strcspn to remove the newline)

Comment: You are indeed correct, the pattern I was thinking of would only occur it the column was also overflowing. Apologies! I have removed my incorrect comments and deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added this:

```
database_publishers[pointer].name[strcspn(database_publishers[pointer].name, "\n")] = 0;
database_publishers[pointer].client[strcspn(database_publishers[pointer].client, "\n")] = 0;
```

after fgets calls and now it works like it should
i've found it here: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score -1):

You are using "\n" in the program. Try removing it

Comment: no, fgets just puts \n in the end of the input